# Looking for JQuery drag and drop features

Tags: jquery, html, forms, drag-and-drop

Here's what I want to achieve.

I want to be able to have a list of words, which I can drag over an input field and drop into the value. I want to be able to do this multiple times possibly with the same word, to go in more that one input field.

Basically I'm sorting words into groups.

If anyone could point me at a JQuery library that can do this sort of thing, that would be great.

Cheers,
Thomas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery UI's draggable and droppable functions:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ and http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: The droppable function seems to stop working when I select the html object by class and not ID.

Comment: @diggers It should work. Check over your codes carefully. If you still can't solve it you can always post a question here.